# Docker container with Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel 4.15

Tags: 16.04, kernel, docker

I want to run a docker container with ubuntu 16.04 and kernel 4.15.

Using the image:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

I get kernel version 4.14.

I have been trying to update the kernel in the docker build without any success.
I tried the folowing:

```
  # Update kernel script
  wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_all.deb
  wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb
  wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-image-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb
  dpkg -i *.deb
```

and also to install this package:

```
RUN apt-get install --install-recommends -y linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Is there an available image to use with 4.15 kernel already included?
Are there any more steps to use the 4.15 kernel?